# Device in landscape but [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] reports portrait

Tags: ios6

My project settings indicate Landscape Left and Right are supported interface orientations.
When my app launches the simulator is in landscape.

However, this NSLog statement (in either my App Delegate or my Root View Controller) doesn't get run.

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
    NSLog(@"I'm in landscape");
}
```

Any idea why?

I'm using iOS6.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Using this delegate and the application will be present in Landscape mode or any desired orientation mode.

Try it.